# How To Include a External Script file using script tag in angular5

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

Hi I Want to include a script file in index.html in angular5.after i have included it gives the following error  not found i used ng serve to run the application  but the server haven't loaded the required files.

Please Help me to Solve The Issue.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: what are all the external script files you have been used.

Comment: show your app structure

Comment: Here is The Screenshot of My APP STRUCTURE http://prntscr.com/hwc0ms

Comment: here is the script files screenshot i included http://prntscr.com/hwc1al

Comment: here is the screenshot of error i am getting http://prntscr.com/hwc32x

Comment: can you hit the URL http://localhost:4200/lightslider.js in browser and see whether the JS is loading fine ? if not can you double check the path once?

Comment: here is the screenshot http://prntscr.com/hwca6k it is not showing it gives notfound error

Comment: which means you JS in not loading in local even. So you have to debug from that end i guess,

Comment: ok  actually i want to include one jquery plugin to index.html i wrote the script tag with path to that file but angular server is not taking that file to server thats what my issue is

Comment: it is giving another error here is the screenshot http://prntscr.com/hwcqh3